# How to mapStateToProps only after the component receives data from Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux

In the application I'm trying to render data, based on the route parameters.

When I run the code, I receive an error screen because mapStateToProps hasn't received data from Firestore and the .find() function cannot run on 'undefined'.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const id = ownProps.match.params.product_id;

  return {
    product: state.firestore.ordered.products.find(p => p.id === id)
  };
};
```

I've tried using conditional rendering inside the component itself but the error is inside the mapStateToProps(). The data doesn't even get to the component because the script is stopped at the first attempt of mapping the state to its props.

Here is my component without conditional rendering, for reference.

```
<div className="product-detail-page top-padding container col-lg-10">
        <div className="product-desc">
          <div className="product-desc-image col-lg-5">
            <img
              src={this.props.product.image}
              alt={this.props.product.name}
              className="col-12"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="product-desc-right col-lg-7">
            <h2 className="product-desc-title">{this.props.product.name}</h2>
            <div className="product-desc-bottom-section">
              <div className="product-desc-text">
                <p>
                  In stock - Ships from Ireland. Sold and Shipped by{" "}
                  <span className="comp-logo">
                    <Link to="/">
                      comp<span className="red-dot">.</span>com
                    </Link>
                  </span>
                </p>
                <ul>
                  <li>{this.randomDetails(1)}</li>
                  <li>{this.randomDetails(2)}</li>
                  <li>{this.randomDetails(3)}</li>
                  <li>{this.randomDetails(4)}</li>
                  <li>{this.randomDetails(5)}</li>
                  <li>{this.randomDetails(6)}</li>
                </ul>
                <div className="star-rating">
                  <img src={this.starRating(1)} alt="*" />
                  <img src={this.starRating(2)} alt="*" />
                  <img src={this.starRating(3)} alt="*" />
                  <img src={this.starRating(4)} alt="*" />
                  <img src={this.starRating(5)} alt="x" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="product-desc-checkout">
                <div className="product-desc-total">
                  <h4>€ {this.preTaxCalculator().toFixed(2)}</h4>
                  <p>VAT - € {this.taxCalculator().toFixed(2)}</p>
                  <p>Shipping: € {this.props.product.shipping}</p>
                  <h3>{this.props.product.price}</h3>
                </div>
                <div className="product-desc-action-buttons">ADD TO CART</div>
                <div className="product-desc-action-buttons">
                  ADD TO WISHLIST
                </div>
                <div className="product-desc-action-buttons">
                  SAVE FOR LATER
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="product-details">
          <h2>Learn more about the {this.props.product.name}</h2>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              {this.renderKeys().map(key => (
                <tr key={key}>
                  <td>{key}</td>
                  <td>{this.props.product.details[key]}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const id = ownProps.match.params.product_id;
  if (state.firestore.ordered.products) {
    return {
      product: state.firestore.ordered.products.find(p => p.id === id)
    };
  }
};
```

I used an if statement in the mapStateToProps.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a conditional in your mapStateToProps function. Check whether you have the data or not, and return an empty array, object, or the thing that suits you best, if the data is not available. When the state changes, the function maps again with the real deal.

Comment: Hey, I've just applied conditional rendering on a fraciton of the code and commented the rest. I console.logged this.props.product and it return undefined only once, BEFORE the data it received from Firebase. Because of that the component is not rendered.

Answer (score 0):

you could use condition to check for props and render only if available. Note the changes and also make use of timeout to delay the return

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const id = ownProps.match.params.product_id;
setTimeout(()=>
  return {
    product: state.firestore.ordered.products.find(p => p.id === id)
  }),3000)
};

 {this.props.product && <div className="product-detail-page top-padding container col-lg-10">
                <div className="product-desc">
                  <div className="product-desc-image col-lg-5">
                    <img
                      src={this.props.product.image}
                      alt={this.props.product.name}
                      className="col-12"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="product-desc-right col-lg-7">
                    <h2 className="product-desc-title">{this.props.product.name}</h2>
                    <div className="product-desc-bottom-section">
                      <div className="product-desc-text">
                        <p>
                          In stock - Ships from Ireland. Sold and Shipped by{" "}
                          <span className="comp-logo">
                            <Link to="/">
                              comp<span className="red-dot">.</span>com
                            </Link>
                          </span>
                        </p>
                        <ul>
                          <li>{this.randomDetails(1)}</li>
                          <li>{this.randomDetails(2)}</li>
                          <li>{this.randomDetails(3)}</li>
                          <li>{this.randomDetails(4)}</li>
                          <li>{this.randomDetails(5)}</li>
                          <li>{this.randomDetails(6)}</li>
                        </ul>
                        <div className="star-rating">
                          <img src={this.starRating(1)} alt="*" />
                          <img src={this.starRating(2)} alt="*" />
                          <img src={this.starRating(3)} alt="*" />
                          <img src={this.starRating(4)} alt="*" />
                          <img src={this.starRating(5)} alt="x" />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className="product-desc-checkout">
                        <div className="product-desc-total">
                          <h4>€ {this.preTaxCalculator().toFixed(2)}</h4>
                          <p>VAT - € {this.taxCalculator().toFixed(2)}</p>
                          <p>Shipping: € {this.props.product.shipping}</p>
                          <h3>{this.props.product.price}</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div className="product-desc-action-buttons">ADD TO CART</div>
                        <div className="product-desc-action-buttons">
                          ADD TO WISHLIST
                        </div>
                        <div className="product-desc-action-buttons">
                          SAVE FOR LATER
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="product-details">
                  <h2>Learn more about the {this.props.product.name}</h2>
                  <table>
                    <tbody>
                      {this.renderKeys().map(key => (
                        <tr key={key}>
                          <td>{key}</td>
                          <td>{this.props.product.details[key]}</td>
                        </tr>
                      ))}
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>}
```

Comment: Hey, I've just applied conditional rendering on a fraciton of the code and commented the rest. I console.logged this.props.product and it return undefined only once, BEFORE the data it received from Firebase. Because of that the component is not rendered.

Comment: You can make use of either setTimeout to delay or use setInterval loop until result is available to return and clear the interval